# App is crashing with error for some users Stating Resource not found

Tags: android

I see some random crashes happening with the following exception in playstor for some users

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{views.activities.SplashActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)



Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable (missing name) with resource ID #0x7f080141
```

I have analyzed the apk and checked the resource id . it was notification_bg_tile. Can you help me with .

and such drawable is not there and not used any where in the code

0x7f080141  notification_template_icon_bg   argb8(0x3333b5e5)

[image]

Comment: you might be using some resource with the name notification_bg_tile in the app. try cleaning the code and re running gradle sync

Comment: no where i am using that . this error comes in  splash

Comment: share your splash activity and manifest file @sanjana

Comment: <application
        android:name=".DarkLightInitApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_app_icon_new"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_app_icon_round_new"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        >

Comment: Can you share xml file?

Comment: Check if you have all drawable files for this resource; each with proper dpi size for different screen resolutions

Comment: can you tell me on which android versions you are getting crashes? Generally, I faced random crashes due to svg drawables in Android versions 6 and below. That might be the case for you too. So, check that.

Comment: @primo crash device details  Device
Brand:LGE
Model:Nexus 5X
Orientation: Portrait
RAM free: 1.31 GB
Disk free: 418.99 MB
Operating System
Version:Android 8.1.0
Orientation: Portrait
Rooted:No.   and the exceptionis Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable (missing name) with resource ID #0x7f080141

Comment: On which versions of android did you faced with this error?

Comment: As your error say something regarding constraint layout please Check  constraint layout is updated to latest version:

 implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4" and if you are using correct  constraint layout in xml     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ...